# Latest Tor upgrade not working on Win10 X64

Tags: windows

I have two different Win10 X64 machines.  The Tor browser told me it was out of date, so I let it upgrade 6.0.1 This was this week.  Now Tor will not even open the page that says loading Tor browser.  It also did not try to configure.  This was the same on both machines.  Both have all the Microsoft update.  I got real frustrated and deleted the tor directory and tried to reload 6.0.1 with the same results.  I then decided to go back to the latest version I had saved, so I wiped out the tor browser again and reloaded version "torbrowser-install-5.54_en-US.exe" which works, but of course tell me it is out of date.  The version will work on both machines.

Does anyone know what is going on.

Comment: Do you have Trusteer Rapport installed?

Comment: Yes I do.  Also both machines are using SSD for drive C and all the User files are on drive d:/users/myname/

Answer (score 0):

I stopped Trusteer Rapport and TOR installed 6.0.1 and it ran.
Now if I enable Trusteer Rapport it will not run.  My bank requires that I
am running Trusteer Rapport.  Do you know of anyway to make them compatible
with each other.  Previous versions of Tor was compatible.

Tom

Comment: Please write a mail to trusteer. In the past they fixed it very fast.

Comment: I contacted them, they say it will be fixed in the next release of Trusteer.